# relation on algebraic numbers being zeros of polynomial modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm afraid I might not choose correct terms.

What I want to find is whether it is able to find an equivalence relation on (need not to be whole but maximal) a set of algebraic numbers, which satisfies the following: ($p$ is a prime)

- if two integer-coefficient polynomials are same in $\mathbb Z_p [x]$, then the roots must be equivalent. For example, $x^3 - 1$ and $x^3 + 27$ are the same modulo $7$. Then their roots $1$, $ 3$ and other 4 imaginary roots must be related.
  Note some algebraic numbers such as $m/p \in \mathbb Q$ cannot be discussed since $px-m \equiv -m$ in $\mathbb Z_p$. Similarly, do not consider about polynomials with nonzero coefficient of highest degree divisible by $p$.

Would there be a proper way to construct such an equivalence relation?

Some comments:

> Why $p$ is a prime?
>
> $(x-p)(x-q)=x^2-(p+q)x+pq \equiv x(x-p-q)$ mod $pq$ means that $p\sim 0$ or $q \sim 0$ which is not wanted.

Comment: Why are $\pm 3$ roots of $x^2-1\;(\text{mod}\,7)$ or $x^2 + 27\;(\text{mod}\,7)$?

Comment: @quasi My mistake, modified.

Comment: You mean $-3$, not $+3$, right?